Github action: how to get the name of a pull request's target branch, after changing it?
I wrote a workflow for a github repository,with the intention of having it failed if you try to merge a non release branch to the main branch.
Here is the job doing so:
  name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - 'skip-ci-*'
  pull_request:
    branches-ignore:
      - 'skip-ci-*'
    
permissions:
  contents: write
    
env:
    REPOSITORY_MIRROR: "my-repo.git"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Fetch repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Build
        run: |
          make
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Build failed"
            exit 1
          fi

  tests:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Fetch repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name : run_tests
        run: |
          make tests_run
              
  # push:
  #   needs: tests
  #   runs-on: ubuntu-latest


  #   if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}

  #   steps:
  #     - name: checkout
  #       uses: actions/checkout@v4
  #       with:
  #         fetch-depth: 0
  #         target_repo_url: ${{ env.REPOSITORY_MIRROR }}
  #         ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.GIT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      
  #     - name: Push changes
  #       uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
  #       with: 
  #           fetch-depth: 0
  #           target_repo_url: ${{ env.REPOSITORY_MIRROR }}
  #           ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.GIT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}


  can-merge-pr:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check branchs names
        run: |
          source=${{ github.head_ref }}
          target=${{ github.base_ref }}
          if [ $source == $target ]; then
            echo "Branches are the same"
            exit 1
          fi
          if [ "$target" == "main" ] && [[ "$source" != "Release"* ]]; then
            echo "You can't merge into main from a branch that is not a release branch"
            exit 1
          fi

  create_release:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && startsWith(github.event.pull_request.head.ref, 'Release') == true }}
    needs: can-merge-pr 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Delete Existing Release (if any)
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ startsWith(github.event.pull_request.head.ref, 'Release') }} == true ]]; then
            echo "Condition met. Proceeding."
          else
            echo "Condition not met. Skipping."
          fi
          release_id=$(curl -s \
            -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/releases/tags/${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} \
            | jq -r '.id')
          
          if [ "$release_id" != "null" ]; then
            curl -X DELETE \
              -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/releases/$release_id
          fi

      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
          release_name: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
          body: |
            ${{ github.event.pull_request.body}}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false

      - name: Upload Binary to Release
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./
          asset_name: test.sh
          asset_content_type: application/octet-stream


Although there might be easier ways to do so, it does work as I intended to.
However, someone created a pr from a random branch to main, so, as expected, we can't merge it. I changed the target branch of the pr to another branch, afterward the workflow still got the main branch as a target.
I found that it is because the environment is created at the creation of the event, in this case, when the pr was created, and then it does not update when we restart the workflow.
Can you help me on this problem?

can you share your full yaml?
did you print the values of source and target vars?

I did print them, but after changing the target, i still got main as the output
